# rails transaction rollback results in discontinuous id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, transactions, rollback

I am using postgresql and rails 4.2 for my application development.

Here is the issue:

When a user model is being created, I need two other model associated with user model to be created at meantime: profile model and user_behavior model. In case to keep the consistency of records, transaction is used like this:

```
begin
  @new_user = User.new
  @new_user.transaction do
    @new_user.update_attributes!(users_params)
    @new_user.profile = Profile.create!(profiles_params)
    @new_user.user_behavior = UserBehavior.create!
  end
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => exception
  render_response_msg(4003, { message: exception.message })
rescue ArgumentError => exception
  render_response_msg(4003, { message: "invalid parameters" })
end
@new_user
```

Both user model and profile model has some validations

**problem 1.** I use an instance variable **@new_user** to bring the new created user record out of transaction scope, I am not sure this is generic method to do this, any other ideas?

**problem 2.** when the user params is good, it passes and create a user record, then profile params is not valid, makes the whole transaction rollback. Then I found the id(basic auto increment id of model in rails) of user model is discontinous. For example, if it fails twice because of profile params, then the success transaction will create of model with id = 3. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why are gaps in `id` values a problem? They'll be unique, that's all that's really guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

[**Edit the response to problem 1 is not possible because the local variable cannot be returned as I had pointed out in my comment I missed that in my original post**]

In response to problem 1: 
I think the description provided in this article http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html 
would be helpful. Consequently I would do something as follows:

```
User.transaction do
    new_user = User.new(user_params)
    new_user.profile = Profile.create!(profile_params)
    new_user.behavior = UserBehavior.create!
    new_user.save!
end
```

In response to problem 2: as [mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) pointed out, it should not matter, however postgresql uses a sequence table for every table in the database generally named `[YOUR_TABLE_NAME]_id_seq` you will have to alter the value of the last_value column in that table in order to adjust the id sequence however a mistake would definitely cause a lot of problems with regard to maintaining the uniqueness, and I would certainly advise against playing around with it.

Comment: Notice I need to return new created user record in this method, if **new_user** is used as local variable, I can not retrieve the entity out of transaction scope.

Comment: Oh yes! I am so sorry I absolutely missed that. I will edit my answer

Comment: Also I think you can achieve what you are trying to without an instance variable if you initialize your variable as `new_user` before the transaction it should still be accessible within the `begin` block. you can add a `return new_user` just before `rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => exception ` and if you do not want to return at that point and need new_user accessible outside the `begin` block then initialize `new_user` before the `begin` block starts.

Comment: OK, thank you for your kindly reply, Ruby closure,  I got it. It's my fault I didn't explain clearly. I want to return the instance variable to views, so here I use instance variable. I want to ask actually is that, as my code, initialize a model out of transaction then update its attributes inside the scope. Is there a more common or elegance way to complete this. Thank you again.

Comment: Oh now I get it. Well if it has to be returned to the view you will need an instance variable. I do not know of another way you could achieve what you are trying to. Thank you for the clarification.